# Do changing background permissions deactivate an existing chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

**Question**: Does Chrome deactivate an extension if the permissions only change to include `background` for background pages?

**Backstory**: I'm updating an existing chrome extension (that currently doesn't have a background page) to include one, and as such, I need to update the permissions inside the `manifest.json`.

I'm worried that Chrome will see the new permission in the updated extension and disable it for the existing users until they confirm the permissions update. However, when testing the new permissions, it doesn't seem that the permissions dialogue box that would show is any different (it just contains a list of URLs, just as before).

Comment: You can test it on a private dummy extension. AFAIK it shouldn't trigger the warning, otherwise I'd consider it a bug that needs fixing.

Comment: Alas, on a dummy extension it does trigger the warning and disables the extension. Sounded like a bug to me too.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Chrome disabled the extensions and show a popup mentioning the same. User has to re-enable the extension to use it again. To prevent this, you can use 'optional_permission' in manifest.json and can dynamically request user to accept additional permissions. This prevents default disabling.

You can read more about this here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions

Comment: Thanks Akansh! This is exactly what I need. However, after looking into optional_permissions, it seems I have another issue: I need a background page. I've posted a new question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471757/chrome-extension-optional-permissions-without-background-page) - any idea?