# Chrome extension: optional permissions without background page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

Is it possible to use optional_permissions in a chrome extension without a background page?

I have an extension that doesn't currently have a background page, but I would like to add one, which requires a change to the ext's permissions. However, if I update the permissions, the ext will be disabled for my users until they accept the new permissions.

I would like to add `background` as an optional permission so I can programatically ask the user to approve the permissions and not deactivate the ext altogether, but I can't find a way to use `optional_permissions` without a background page.

This seems like a catch-22 to me. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Are you wanting to have a [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) or actually declare the [`"background"` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions#background)? Declaring the `"background"` permission is a separate development choice from having a background page. Most extensions have a background page, but do not declare the `"background"` permission.

Comment: There should be no need to change the extensions permissions *just* to have a background page. The permissions might change because of something you *do* in the background page, but not just because of the existence of the background page.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks so much, Makyen! I conflated the `background` permission with the existence of a background page. You are the best!